# Does the Carcassonne Hunters & Gatherers tile with 3 fish, 2 rivers and 2 forests have a menhir?

Tags: carcassonne

Does the second tile from the right in the extract from the rule book below contain a menhir?
[image]
The rule book lists it under menhir tiles, but so does the one with the 2 lakes which obviously does not contain a menhir.

<strike>It seems to be the only tile with an L-shaped forest that does not have the usual picture of a menhir.</strike> Other such menhir tiles are the one with a mammoth and an auroch, one with a pit trap and one with mushrooms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple answer: If the tile doesn't have a picture of a menhir, it doesn't contain a menhir.

I suspect the point of confusion here is differentiating between "tiles with a menhir on them" and "menhir tiles". The menhir tiles are a special stack of tiles that you play from *after* you complete a forest with a menhir in it; these ones all have a special back and should not be shuffled in with the regular tiles:

[image: Three different tile backs]

<sup>(note: other editions of the rulebook refer to the menhir tiles as "bonus tiles", which is boring but also less ambiguous.)</sup>

*Those* menhir tiles are the ones listed in the instructions you quoted, to showcase their added value. This does not mean, nor is meant to mean, that the menhir tiles *also* contain a menhir.